# Why does TextField inherit from javafx.scene.Parent in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am reading javafx TextField API:

```
 java.lang.Object
    javafx.scene.Node
        javafx.scene.Parent
            javafx.scene.layout.Region
                javafx.scene.control.Control
                    javafx.scene.control.TextInputControl
                        javafx.scene.control.TextField
```

As you see, TextField inherits from javafx.scene.Parent class. From Parent class javadoc `The base class for all nodes that have children in the scene graph.` But I can't understand what child nodes TextField can have. Can anyone explain?

Comment: all controls inheret from parent - and most if not all actually have children, in case of a textfield f.i. the caret or the prompt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a `TextField` is not made up of a single `Node`. For instance, it uses (different) `Text` nodes for the prompt and normal text. It also uses a `Path` for the caret. For `Control`s, this is implemented using a `Skin` (e.g. `TextInputControlSkin` and `TextFieldSkin`).

Notice, however, that `TextField` doesn't *expose* its children publicly for modification; random code can't just go adding nodes to it. But you can view the children in an unmodifiable fashion.

Comment: if you are determined to add custom children (with full risk!) - its skin does expose an modifiable list :)

Comment: @kleopatra Technically, yes :) Though it's the `SkinBase` class that exposes the modifiable list and using it is an implementation detail (even if virtually every implementation of `Skin` extends `SkinBase`).

Comment: well spotted - was too lazy to repeat the details over comments <g>

Answer (score 1):

It can have any child node you want it to - there's no *inherent* reason why you couldn't add something like a label, a graphic, or a weird shape as its child. Try it out - it works!

In practice you probably wouldn't do this, you'd add both the textfield and the weird shape (or whatever else) to a StackPane or similar instead, as that gives you greater control over layout and extensibility.

Comment: nit-picking: parent allows only access of its children only via an unmodifiable list, so you would need to subclass for custom children - to add to the list you would do it via its skin (requiring a type-cast to SkinBase)